# setHeight() for ImageView crop from bottom

Tags: android

What I want is to cut (not actual cropping using canvas) image from top (instead bottom) on setting height dynamically using `imageView.setHeight()`

Is it possible in android ?

---

Guess a picture of man. (Head at top & legs at bottom) :P

I am setting height dynamically using layoutparam as posted below by other developers.

When I set height for instance 300,

It sets height from HEAD to 300 units toward legs of image.

What I want is to set height from LEGs to top 300 units.

Comment: use scaleType feature of ImageView

Comment: See my point below horizontal line in question and ack. please. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
image.setLayoutParams(
          new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                your width, 
                 your height));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple only,

```
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 100;//Your desired height
```